# Rename windows 7 64bit installed printers using vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I want to change printer name dynamically .. i did this for 32 bit using VBSCRIPT

how to do this for windows 7

```
Const strFolder = "C:\MEDALL_PRINT_SERVICE\"

 Dim oFSO

 Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

 If Not oFSO.FolderExists(strFolder) Then
 oFSO.CreateFolder strFolder
 End If

 strComputer = "."
 Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
 & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colPrinters =  objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_Printer Where DeviceID = 'PDFCreator'")

For Each objPrinter in colPrinters
objPrinter.RenamePrinter("MEDALL PRINT SERVICE")
Next

Set colPrinters = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * From Win32_Printer Where DeviceID = 'MEDALL PRINT SERVICE' ")

For Each objPrinter in colPrinters
objPrinter.ShareName = "MEDALL PRINT SERVICE"
objPrinter.Put_
Next
```

How to do this... ?

Comment: What isn't working? What error are you getting with this script and on what line?

Comment: printer name is not getting changed

Comment: Does it fall over with an error? If so, where? What debugging have you done so far - for example do your WMI queries return any rows? How far through the code have you traced? We need more information on exactly how far you have traced as we can't debug this code for you if it's running without error.

Comment: By the way, one debug tool is the command line tool `WMIC`, for example if your WMI queries return no data, then check from the command line, for example `WMIC PATH Win32_Printer WHERE "DeviceID = 'PDFCreator'" GET DeviceID,Sharename,Name,Drivername`, or exclude the `WHERE` clause completely for everything. This might help give you pointers into your script if you're not getting back the data you expect in your WMI queries.